# How to call a WCF Service with TLS from monodroid

Tags: c#, android, wcf, security, xamarin.android

I have a WCF Service which I need to call from a monodroid app. The connection needs to be secure because I don't want users to just start something like fiddler and read the data. I tried to use BasicHttpBinding with Transport security and client- and servercertificates but I don't know how to specify the clientcertificate in the android app. I found some old questions where people say that it's not possible in monodroid but I don't know if this is still the case.

If it is still not supported by monodroid what is the best I can do to secure the connection?
Is something like [Halibut](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/554692/Halibut-a-secure-communication-stack-for-NET-Mono) a good alternative?

My current code looks like this:

Web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <services>
    <service name="WcfTestService"
             behaviorConfiguration="WcfTestServiceBehavior">
      <endpoint address=""
                binding="basicHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBinding1"
                contract="IWcfTestService"/>
    </service>
  </services>
  <bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="basicHttpBinding1">
        <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="WcfTestServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
        <serviceCredentials>
          <serviceCertificate findValue="WcfTest"
                              storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                              storeName="My"
                              x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
          <clientCertificate>
            <certificate findValue="WcfTest"
                         storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                         storeName="My"
                         x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
          </clientCertificate>
        </serviceCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Client:

```
BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding
{
    Name = "basicHttpBinding1",
    MaxBufferSize = 214783647,
    MaxReceivedMessageSize = 214783647
};
TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
binding.SendTimeout = timeout;
binding.OpenTimeout = timeout;
binding.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;

EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("https://192.168.94.64/WcfTestService/WcfTestService.svc");

WcfTestServiceClient client = new WcfTestServiceClient(binding, endpoint);
//client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate; //ClientCertificate does not exist
```